# Make image size responsive inside iframe

Tags: html, css

I have an iframe on a page that will display an image file I am hosting.

I can make the iframe responive so that it get's larger or smaller depending on window size but am looking to have the actual image in the iframe scale to fit the iframe as opposed to having the scroll bars appear when the iframe gets smaller than the image. Is there a way to do this?

Below is the code I am working with where http://example.net/picture.jpg is the hosted image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var frm = ['gallery', 'info'];
        var hrf = ['http://example.com/', 'http://example.net/picture.jpg'];

        function setSource() {
            for(i=0, l=frm.length; i<l; i++) {
                document.querySelector('iframe[name="'+frm[i]+'"]').src = hrf[i];
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe src="" name="gallery"></iframe>
    <iframe src="" name="info"></iframe>
    <span onclick="javascript: setSource();">Click me</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't mind using css and jquery, you can constantly change the size of an image to a percent.  That's a hint.

Comment: "Is there a way to do this?" ... there's always a way. 1. research, 2. try it by yourself, 3. come back if something doesn't work as expected ;-)

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Just set the image to `display: block; width: 100%;` or use it as a `background-image` on `body` in the iframe source.

Comment: @StefanBob - I've updated my question with the code I'm working with.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - Thanks, I will try this but I'm a bit lost on how to start. Is that something I could tack on the src somehow?

Comment: @ad_on_is - You're right, I'm sure there is a way. Where I'm stuck is that I can get the actual iframe to resize fine but not the source. If you have a hint, I'll appreciate it and work from there, otherwise, I'll keep researching like you said ;)

Comment: @Jake use CSS. In the iframe you could add to the `body` tag `<body style="background: url('http://example.net/picture.jpg') center center no-repeat / cover;"></body>` and you can change `center center` to other values. that's `background-position` so it will set where the image is positioned within that element.